# Failed startup after 10.10. upgrade

Tags: macos, startup, sandbox

After upgrading to 10.10.4 from 10.10.2, my Macbook Pro (late 2013) boots up to a blank screen with the mouse cursor displayed briefly every 10 seconds. Booting to safe mode and resetting the SMC or PRAM have not worked.

Booting into recovery mode and examining /var/log/system.log, sandbox permissions appear to prevent several services from starting, including sandboxd itself.

```
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost fseventsd[43]: log dir: /.fseventsd getting new uuid: 4BCE743F-CABB-4535-AA36-4CCCE8DA761A
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: IOHIDService compatibility thread running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.parallels.mobile.dispatcher.launchdaemon): Service has increased maximum shutdown time to 150 seconds. This will create a poor experience for the user.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[78]: Session 100000 created
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Service specifies neither Program nor ProgramArguments.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Could not import service from caller: path = /Library/LaunchDaemons/PPPMonitord.plist, caller = launchd.1, error = 111: Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.adobe.adobeupdatedaemon): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool): Unknown key for string: SHAuthorizationRight
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.alf): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.audio.coreaudiod): Unknown key for array: seatbelt-profiles
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.auditd): The TimeOut key is no longer respected. It never did anything anyway.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.autofsd): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.backupd-status): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost powerd[49]: Failed to read current rating(0xe00002f0)
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost watchdogd[53]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_watchdog_open) - IOIteratorNext failed (kr=0)
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost watchdogd[53]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(      wd_daemon_init) - could not initialize the hardware watchdog
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost watchdogd[53]:  [watchdog_daemon] @(                main) - cannot initialize the watchdog service
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 64 dlt 12
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.FileSyncAgent.PHD.isRunning): The HideUntilCheckIn property is an architectural performance issue. Please transition away from it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbpluginhost.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mbloginhelper.user): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.secd): The ServiceIPC key is no longer respected. Please remove it.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent): This key does not do anything: OnDemand
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[78]: Entering service
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost iconservicesagent[60]: iconservicesagent launched.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost powerd[49]: Activity changes from 0xffff to 0x1. Assertions:1 HidState:0
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: opendirectoryd(70) deny network-outbound /private/var/run/syslog
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read hw.pagesize_compat
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.cfprefsd.daemon
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.opendirectoryd.libinfo
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read hw.pagesize_compat
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(1S3a4n)d bdoexny system-privile:ge  1s00a2n
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sadnbdobxoxd:( s1a3n4d)b odxd(134)e ndye nsyy sscysttle-mr-epardi vhiwl.epgea ge10s0i2z
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: e_compat
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read hw.pagesize_compat
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny signal 134
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties Open
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox:S ansdabnodxb:ox da(u1t3h4d)( 1d2e7ny)  sydsteenmy-p riiovkilite-ggee t-1p0r0o2p
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: ertiesS andCbooxn:t esnatn dbHoixndt(
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: auth1d3(412)7 ) ddeenyn ys iigonkailt -ge1t3-4p
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: roperties Ejectable
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties Preferred Block Size
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties Removable
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iSoakint-dgbeotx-:pr opsertaiensd boxSidz(e
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: a13u4t)h d(d1e2n7y)  sydsetneym -iporkiivti-lgeegte- pr1op0e0r2t
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxide(s1 34W)h odleen
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(y1 27)s idgennayl  i1o3S4kandbox: sandbox
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: d(134) deny sysctl-read ikte-rng.eptro-cp.rpoipde.1r2t7i
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: es Writable
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties IOBootDevice
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) dSenya nidobkoixt-:g esta-npdrobpoexrdt(ie13s4 ) UdUeInDy
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: aut hsd(yst1e2m7-)pr idevnilye gieoki t-10g0e2t
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: -properties CoreStorage
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(1S2a7n)d bodxe:n sya ionkdibto-xgde(t-13p4r)o pdeerntyie ss ysCtoermeS-tproirvaiglee gEne cr1y0p0te2d
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties CoreStorage CPDK
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties CorSeaSntdorbaoge xL:VG  sUaUnIDd
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) denyb oixokdi(t1-g3e4)t -prdopeerntyi ess CyosrteeSmto-rpargiev iLlVF egUeU ID1
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-proper0t0ie2s
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: IOStorageSFaeantudresb
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iookxi:t-get-pr opsaenrtdbieosx d(B1S3D4 )Name
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(1 27)d ednenyy  iokit-gsetys-tperomper-tpireisv iBSlDe gUnei t
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny ioki1t0-0ge2t
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: -properties BSD MajorSandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-getp-rpirvoipleergtei es100 2
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: BSD Minor
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties IOBusyInterest
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny iokit-get-properties IOGeneralInterest
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.PowerManagement.control
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.DataDetectorsDynamicData): The JoinExistingSession key is only available to Application services.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read hw.pagesize_compat
Jul  8 13:40:37 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny signal 127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny sysctl-read kern.hostid
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny system-audit
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Media on device disk0s4
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny system-privilege 1002
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.SecurityServer
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost distnoted[101]: # distnote server daemon  absolute time: 3.058401606   civil time: Wed Jul  8 13:40:37 2015   pid: 101 uid: 241  root: yes
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny file-write-data /dev/dtracehelper
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny system-audit
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: ____IOHIDSessionScheduleAsync_block_invoke: thread_id=0x10e704000
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: HID Session async scheduling initiated.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: HID Session async root queue running at priority 63 and schedule 2.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: authd(127) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.opendirectoryd.libinfo
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(134) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost com.apple.usbmuxd[77]: usbmuxd-345.70 on Jan 26 2015 at 16:55:11, running 64 bit
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en0. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: en0: channel changed to 1
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: en0::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 94 dlt 163
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 30 dlt 105
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 52 dlt 127
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost kernel[0]: bpfAttach len 38 dlt 192
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost configd[48]: preference: no sharing preferences
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: HID Session async scheduling complete.
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost hidd[97]: Successfully opened the IOHIDSession
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost fseventsd[43]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
Jul  8 13:40:37 localhost configd[48]: network changed.
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro.local configd[48]: setting hostname to "Jonahs-MacBook-Pro.local"
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny file-read-metadata /var
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny mach-lookup com.apple.cfprefsd.daemon
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro.local thermald[45]: Waiting for OSTT support notification
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.notification_center
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny sysctl-read kern.hostname
Jul  8 13:40:37 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Sandbox: blued(84) deny mach-lookup com.apple.system.logger
```

The services are restarted every 10 seconds.

```
Jul  8 13:40:46 Jonahs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.loginwindow): Service only ran for 8 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 2 seconds.
```

Any suggestions? .sb files in /System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles all seem to be fine.

There's a longer log [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/995aead7d29a2a4a9a73).

Comment: can you try to boot in verbose mode to see where it hangs ?

Comment: Also could you take care of the "powerd", it should not be there, so reset the SMC, make sure the battery is charged or charging.

Comment: Battery seems fine in recovery mode. I will try to reset the SMC again. It doesn't really hang, different services/processes just keep trying to start over and over again. /var/log/system.log has everything shown in verbose mode. The screen goes blank after a while, with the mouse pointer flashing briefly every 10 seconds.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, in that after the latest upgrade of OS X, `Login Window Application` crashes. I've even performed a reinstall using the OS X Recovery partition, but the problem persists. Did you sort out your problem?

Comment: No @DagHøidahl I had to re-install. Sorry. You?

Comment: @jhdny I had to reinstall as well. Later, I found out that my problem was due to a failing Security Agent plugin. See [my question about it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205862/28536).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stands out in your log, there are two options...

You can download the 10.10.4 combo update on to another Mac, and using target disk mode on your broken Mac, you can reinstall the update again, ensuring to click Your broken Mac in the installer window, not the local machine...

If you do this do a backup first.

Or you can simply [do an Archive and Install, using the OS X Recovery Partition](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_GB).

Comment: Thanks, but don't have another Mac anywhere close, and bandwidth is precious here. :(

Comment: I understand that, however there isn't really another option, you aren't likely to be able to fix this issue as there is nothing obviously wrong in that log... If you don't have internet access and a Mac that can help with this, i'd take it to an Apple Store to get help.

Comment: I didn't paste the entire log as I was worried it might be too long. More coming up.

Comment: Please find a longer system log [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/onz2g94u3wu0k7s/system.log?dl=0).

Comment: That log confirmed what my suspicion was, your `Login Window Application` is crashing only seconds after boot up, which is what displays the mouse and everything after that...

Comment: I am guessing that you've tried verbose mode, but it isn't much use as it's booting to the login screen then crashing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25662/discussion-between-unknowndomain-and-jnhdny).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same symptoms. The cause in my case was a broken Security Agent plugin. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205862/28536) for a description of the problem and how to fix it.