# How do I uninstall the Proxinator Security Agent Plugin?

Tags: macos, security

A while ago, using OS X Mavericks, I installed an OS X utility named Proxinator, which was supposed to allow me to lock and unlock my Mac by proximity sensing my iPhone using bluetooth and a companion iPhone app. It didn't work well, but I left it installed.

Recently, and after installing Yosemite, there came a security update which prevented me from logging in. The symptoms were basically the same as described in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122938/black-screen-with-cursor-instead-of-login-window), (black screen, flashing cursor instead of login dialog). The error logs pointed to `/Library/Security/SecurityAgentPlugins/proxinator.bundle`. Removing it didn't help, and I was eventually forced to restore a backup that took me back to Mavericks.

Then I tried removing the bundle from the `SecurityAgentPlugins` directory, and I got the same problem with the black screen. Restoring it fixed the problem. So something in the system configuration is evidently expecting a plugin that works, but I can't figure out what.

How can I get rid of a Security Agent Plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: If you are able to log in, you can uninstall Proxinator specifically by running it, and selecting "Reset Proxinator" from its menu.

Complicated answer: You have to edit the Authorization DB using `security authorizationdb read` and `security authorizationdb write`. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21618085/22146).